# Simple query to Oracle SQL using Python 2.3

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, oracle10g, python-2.x

Unfortunately I have a REHL3 and Python 2.3 and no chance of upgrading.

Does anyone have any examples of how to interact with the DB, openning sqlplus, logging in and then I only want a simple SELECT query bring the data to a CSV and then I can figure out the rest.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Why do you mention sqlplus? If you're using Python, you can connect to the database directly using cx_Oracle.

Comment: Yes, but for such a simple thing I thought it would be an overkill.

Comment: Using cx_Oracle is simple. Trying to ensure your python program will always be able to find and run the sqlplus command-line tool, is (IMHO) overkill. I'm pretty sure you can do most of what you want here in just a few lines of python. If you've already got a working SQL*Plus script, on the other hand, I would forego python and just run it in a simple bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I used a bash script to produce the csv file and then manipulated the data with Python.
That was the only solution I could think of with Python 2.3.